# 'try to the court' vs 'try in the court'

Tags: difference, legalese

> [p 7 of 14 of this PDF](https://pennstatelaw.psu.edu/_file/student_servs/Assignments/Ten_Instructions_for_Briefing_Cases_Bateman.pdf): REYNOLDSON, Justice.
>   This action to recover for burglary loss under two separate insurance policies was **[tried to the court](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was+tried+to+the+court%22&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=dxu&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&channel=sb&biw=1024&bih=644&ei=cMx2VJ7PK-XOmwW0ooDgBg&start=0&sa=N)**, resulting in a finding plaintiff had failed to establish a burglary within the policy definitions. Plaintiff appeals from judgment entered for defendant. We reverse and remand.

What are the similarities and differences? The linked Google search shows more of this use. I know that ''try in the court' means [2.1. Investigate and decide (a case or issue) in a formal trial](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/try) in a law court.

Comment: No surprise you found this usage in a law school paper. I think this is a wording seldom found outside of legal circles. (You've asked enough questions about this particular domain that you probably should have figured that out by now – lawyers and judges will say things that you won't typically hear laymen say.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *try to the court* means to submit a matter for decision to a judge or panel of judges instead of to a jury.